# Group by field and have sub-group-by for each result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I don't really know how to title this so that it describes what I'm trying to do. Easier to just show the collections and my desired result.

There's a `permissions` collection that contains permissions and the users or groups that are assigned that permission for a given resource.

`permissions`

```
[
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "resource": "resource:docs/61",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "permission": "role:documentOwner",
          "users": [
            "user:abc",
            "user:def",
            "group:abc",
            "group:bff"
          ]
        },
        {
          "permission": "document.read",
          "users": [
            "user:xxx"
          ]
        },
        {
          "permission": "document.update",
          "users": [
            "user:xxx"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "resource": "resource:docs/38",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "permission": "role:documentOwner",
          "users": [
            "user:abc",
            "user:def",
            "group:abc",
            "group:bff"
          ]
        },
        {
          "permission": "document.read",
          "users": [
            "group:abc",
            "user:xxx"
          ]
        },
        {
          "permission": "document.update",
          "users": [
            "user:xxx"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

And a `groups` collection that assigns users to a group.

`groups`

```
[
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "id": "abc",
      "name": "Test Group",
      "users": [
        "abc"
        "cpo",
        "yyy",
        "xxx"
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "id": "bff",
      "name": "Something",
      "users": [
        "xxx"
      ]
    }
 ]
```

I'm trying to group by users and show their associated groups and resource permissions. I'm almost there but not sure how to group permissions with their associated resource. Here's my desired result...

**Desired Result**

```
{
    "_id": "abc",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "abc",
        "name": "Test Group"
      }
    ],
    "permissions": [
      {
        "permissions": ["document.read", "role:documentOwner"],
        "resource": "resource:docs/61"
      },
      {
        "permissions": ["role:documentOwner"],
        "resource": "resource:docs/38"
      }
    ]
 }
```

This is my current attempt. I've setup a [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G2i3qCAl2Bx) where I've been trying to get this to work. I'm stuck on the last part of grouping the permissions with their resource.

```
db.permissions.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$permissions"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$permissions.users"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "groups",
      "let": {
        "id": "$permissions.users"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    0,
                    {
                      "$indexOfCP": [
                        "$$id",
                        "group:"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$id",
                    {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        {
                          "$split": [
                            "$$id",
                            ":"
                          ]
                        },
                        1
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "groupLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "users": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              {
                "$size": "$groupLookup"
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              {
                "$split": [
                  "$permissions.users",
                  ":"
                ]
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          {
            "$first": "$groupLookup.users"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$users"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "u": "$users",
        "r": "$resource"
      },
      "p": {
        "$addToSet": "$permissions.permission"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will give you the desired output.  Most of the effort is just to deal with the `user:` vs. `group:` prefixes.

```js
 db.foo.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$permissions"},
    {$unwind: "$permissions.users"},

    // Convert array of users and groups into array of                                      
    // just users by looking up and substituting.                                           
    // Note: this could be compactified into the $let statement below...                    
    {$addFields: {"permissions.G": {$cond: [
        {$eq:[0,{$indexOfCP:["$permissions.users","group:"]} ] }, //IF                      
        {$arrayElemAt:[{$split:['$permissions.users',':']},1]},
        null
    ]}
                 }},

    {$lookup: {"from": "foo2",
               let: { gid: "$permissions.G" },
               pipeline: [
                   {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ '$$gid','$id' ]} }},
                   {$project: {_id:false, users:'$users'}}
               ],
               as: "GGG"
              }},

    // Use $project here to carry forward only the fields we want.  If                      
    // GGG is empty, take the one user: and wrap it with [] to make an                      
    // array of one, ELSE ... note that GGG is an array of output which                     
    // we know has either 0 or 1 match.  If 1, then GGG.users dotpath will                  
    // create an array of array from which we only need the $first.                         
    {$project: {
        "resource": true,
        "permissions.permission": true,
        "permissions.users": {$cond:[
            {$eq:[{$size:"$GGG"},0]}, // IF                                                 
            [ {$arrayElemAt:[{$split:['$permissions.users',':']},1]} ], // THEN             
            {$first: '$GGG.users'} // ELSE                                                  
        ]}
    }},

    // .. and now unwind AGAIN:                                                             
    {$unwind: '$permissions.users'},

    // The Famous group-regroup treatment:                                                  
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            u: '$permissions.users',
            r:"$resource"
        },
        // Use addToSet because groups and users may intersect!                             
        p: {$addToSet: "$permissions.permission"}
    }},
    {$group: {_id: '$_id.u', p: {$push: {permissions: '$p', resource: '$_id.r'}} }}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Buzz. At first glance your answer looked correct, however, it's excluding the permissions that a user inherits from their assigned groups. I've set up an example in [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sEPxoHEUWXI). In the results, look at `user:abc`. That user should have both `role:documentOwner` and `document:read` on `resource:docs/61`, but only `role:documentOwner` shows.

Comment: I created another [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BDPJo3h5gJw) where I've deconstructed the groups and associated users. I just continue to get stuck on grouping correctly.

Comment: Your original question above does not have user `abc` in group `abc` but the new playground does.   Also, the `$match` on `user:` is no longer there.  This is the sync danger with playground.   Please edit the question here.

Comment: The `$match` on user was excluding the groups. I'll update my question to appropriately include `user:abc`.

Comment: I've updated my question and the Mongo Playground link. Here's the latest... https://mongoplayground.net/p/G2i3qCAl2Bx. I'm almost there...

Comment: I changed my answer to pick up the group perms.   *EDIT*  Just checked your playground.   We have the same logic -- yours compactifies the group:/user: check directly into `$lookup`.